# Listview inside fragment onitemclick is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application in main view there are 3 tabs. Those 3 tabs are filled with seperate fragment with viewpage adapter. In my second tab , there is a listview (includes in a fragment). When user clicks on a listview I need to show another fragment there. But when user clicks on a listview item I got an error like this

```
No view found for id 0x7f0e008a (com.example.abc.myapp:id/new_output) for fragment MantraFragment{30391e5 #3 id=0x7f0e008a}
```

I found this error in other questions in stackoverflow. Tried solutions of them , but didn't work. Please help me to fix this issue.

Class which includes listview

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment  {
private ListView listView;
private String items[];


public TwoFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.races_array);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();


            Fragment newFrag = new MyNewFragment();
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            newFrag.setArguments(arguments);
            ft.replace(R.id.new_output, newFrag);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}}
```

**MyNewFragment.class**

```
public class MyNewFragment extends Fragment{

public MyNewFragment(){
   }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.mynewfrag_view, container, false);

    return rootView;
}}
```

MyNewFragment view (mynewfrag_view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/msg2"/>


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0b0ff"
        android:id="@+id/new_output" />


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

   private Toolbar toolbar;
   private TabLayout tabLayout;
   private ViewPager viewPager;



  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
       setupViewPager(viewPager);

       tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
       tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
   }


 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
       ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "One");
       adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Two");
       adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Three");

   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   }



 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
       private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
       private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

   public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
       super(manager);
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       return mFragmentList.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return mFragmentList.size();
   }

   public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
       mFragmentList.add(fragment);
       mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
   }

   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
   }   }}
```

MainActivity layout(activity_main)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

PS : I’m still a beginner in Android development and I think it’s good to use a fragment there insted of showing an activity. (Correct me if I’m wrong)

Comment: can you please post the code related to how you are loading your tabs ?. Might be you are loading the child fragment in the base fragment container. That's where you are getting the problem.

Comment: @TrickySolutons- Thank you very much. I have updated the code.

Comment: `<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0b0ff"
        android:id="@+id/new_output" />`

Replace above with FrameLayout
`<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0b0ff"
        android:id="@+id/new_output" />`

It should solve your problem

Comment: @TrickySolutions- Thank you for the answer. I added the code. But got the same error.

Comment: Add your `Activity` layout file

Comment: I didn't get you. Please explain ?

Comment: Add the layout file of your `MainActivity` in the question

Comment: Added.please help

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `MyNewFragment` and giving the `id` of view which is present in `my_newfragment.xml` which is still unknown. You have to add/replace fragment in the layout file of `TwoFragment` i.e. `fragment_two.xml`.

Your `fragment_two.xml` should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ....

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0b0ff"
        android:id="@+id/new_output" />

    ....

</LinearLayout>
```

Remove `fragment` tag `new_output` from `mynewfrag_view.xml` and add in `fragment_two.xml` like above, and check if it works.

Comment: I have added the above code with class with

 <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0b0ff"
        android:id="@+id/new_output"
        class = "com.abc.myapp.view.MyNewFragment"
              />

Now there are no errors. But when i'm clicking an item , nothing happenes

Comment: Don't add `class` attribute. And have you defined this `fragment` tag in `two_fragment.xml`?

Comment: I have added this inside two_fragment.xml  

 <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0b0ff"
        tools:layout="@layout/mynewfrag_view"
        android:id="@+id/new_output"   />

Now getting this error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Why have you added the `tools` attribute? Remove it, just copy and paste `fragment` tag from my answer

Answer (score 0):

**This is not recognising your R.id.new_output used in onclicklistener at TwoFragment class**
`ft.replace(R.id.new_output, newFrag);`